# Is Von Neumann's function application operation defined for all functions and all arguments?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Von Neumann's original axioms of what became [von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) took as primitive notions function and argument.
Accompanying these was a two-variable operation, denoted $[x,y]$, corresponding to function application:

> The operation $[x,y]$ corresponds to a procedure that is encountered everywhere in mathematics, namely, the formation, from a function $f$ (which must be carefully distinguished from its values $f(x)$!) and an argument $x$, of the value $f(x)$ of the function $f$ for the argument $x$. Instead of $f(x)$ we write $[f,x]$ to indicate that $f$, just like $x$, is to be regarded as a variable in this procedure. Through the use of $[x,y]$ we replace, as it were, all one-variable functions by a single two-variable function. In this scheme the elements of the domain of "functions" answer to the functions (conceived naively) that are defined for the "arguments" and whose values are "arguments".
>
> [from von Neumann's 1925 article, *An axiomatization of set theory*, as translated into English in *From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879-1931*, Harvard University Press, pp. 393–413]

I'm trying to understand how the $[f,x]$ operation handles the case where $x$ does not belong to the domain of $f$. I feel like this could arise in certain models of the theory, but in first-order logic, shouldn't an expression such as $[f,x]$ be valid to form for all function letters $f$ and argument letters $x$, since we can't determine whether or not $x$ is in the domain of $f$ without referring to an explicit model? Or, is the last line in the above quotation actually imposing a restriction on how we can use the operation?

Comment: We can manage it as *types* of modern logic: if $f$ is a *predicate* symbol and $t$ is a *term*, the formula $f(t)$ is always correct. According to the interpretation chosen, for some elements of the domain  "named" by $t$ we have that $f(t)$ is FALSE; for otehr it is TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read von Neumann like this: his functions are intended to be total on a universe of what he calls I-objects (i.e., things that intuitively can be arguments and values of functions). The I-objects correspond to sets as opposed to classes in the usual presentation of NBG. Classes correspond to his II-objects and the II-objects include the I-objects. If $x$ is not an I-object, then $[a, x]$ isn't really meaningful and the axioms say nothing about its value. He selects two arbitrary I-objects $A$ and $B$, which are used to represent false and true when a function represents a set. $A$ is also used to act as the "default" value for a function. So a function $f : X \to Y$ in NBG would be represented by two I-objects $f_d$ and $f_v$ representing the domain of $f$ and the values of $f$ separately, thus:

$$
\begin{align*}
[f_d, x] &= \left\{
   \begin{array}{l@{\quad}l}
      A &\mbox{if $x \not\in X$} \\
      B & \mbox{if $x \in X$}
   \end{array}\right. \\
[f_v, x] &= \left\{
   \begin{array}{l@{\quad}l}
      A &\mbox{if $x \not\in X$} \\
      f(x) & \mbox{if $x \in X$}
   \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
$$

This reading is based on von Neumann's axiom IV.2 and his earlier discussion about it. That axiom asserts that a II-object $a$ is not an I-object if the I-objects $x$ such that $[a, x] \neq A$ comprise a proper class and not a set.